# Hive + URI "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Tags: hive

I have a problem when I try to start Hive show this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
```

Do you have any idea how to solve?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Perhaps an example of code? From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26679779).

Comment: This seems like an error in one of your configuration files for hive, or hadoop if you're also using that.  
If you're running hadoop, have a look at core-site.xml, make sure the hadoop.tmp.dir property has the correct value.  
Alternatively look in your hive-env.sh script and check the HADOOP_HOME HIVE_CONF_DIR HIVE_HOME variables have the correct value.  
  
The error says you've written a _relative path_ like "Documents/hive/" when it expects an _absolute path_ like "/home/hadoop/Documents/hive" or "C:\Documents\hive\"  
And your configuration files should have absolute paths.

Comment: Solved! I changed some paths in In hive-site.xml and it was resolved